# Does GVA (Google Voice Assistant) support RTC and Doorbell related fucntionality?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I want to access our doorbell product to Google Voice Assistant, but didn't find the Doorbell type in Google Assistant Doc. https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides

I wonder whether GVA support RTC and Doorbell related functionality such as doorbell notification.
For example:

1. When someone rings the doorbell, the ringing message will be delivered to GVA automatically, and the device with GVA will playing "Someone is ringing the doorbell".
2. The device with GVA can display a live view of Doorbell when user say "show me the doorbell" and user can have a talk with the guest outside with a real time communication(RTC).

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by the platform, but you can subscribe to the [doorbell type request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169526777) on the public tracker to be notified once it is released.

In the the mean time, you could implement the `CameraStream` [trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream) to enable users to request to "Show the front door", though this would need to be proactively requested by the user when they hear a doorbell ring.